# jboss 6.4 EAP threadpool/executor JNDI lookup

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I can't find informations if it's possible and if so then how to expose configured executor as JNDI resource.

this is my configuration inside `standalone.xml`

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1">
        <thread-factory name="spring-async-factory" group-name="spring-thread-pool" thread-name-pattern="spring-async-%t" priority="1"/>
        <blocking-bounded-queue-thread-pool name="spring-async-tp">
            <core-threads count="5"/>
            <queue-length count="100"/>
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="20" unit="seconds"/>
            <thread-factory name="spring-async-factory"/>
        </blocking-bounded-queue-thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
```

I've tried it to access with `java:global/threads/spring-async-tp`, `java:comp/threads/spring-async-tp` but that wasn't found. So if it's possible how can I found it via JNDI?

Answer (score 0):

The `threads` subsystem is deprecated and has been removed in JBoss EAP 7.0. There is also not a way to expose the factory via JNDI. It was the intention of the subsystem to be a reference point for other subsystems to point to a thread factory. It was never the intention that these factories get used in deployments.